# Getting hashmap keys based on parameter value and values lower than it

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

Basically I want to iterate through a hashmap with a value given by the user but also include any smaller values "price" that have keys. Possible values that have keys are 1250, 900, 600, 300.

e.g. If user puts in 600 but there are keys for value 300 print all keys for 600 and 300 value.

This is what I have so far but it will only print the keys for the intial value given not the lower ones.

```
    private Map<Integer, Integer> prices = new HashMap<>();
    private Map<Integer, Integer> bestPrices = new HashMap<>();
```

```
    public void findBestPrice(LithiumPricing obj, Integer value)
    {
        //get hashmap prices from class LithiumPricing.
        prices = obj.getPrices();
        bestPrices.clear();
        if (prices.containsValue(value)){
            for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : prices.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue() <= value){
                     bestPrices.put(entry.getKey(), value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "print"? nothing is printed there

Comment: Your code looks fine. When you try it with the values (1250,900,600,300) and 600 as input, the bestPrices map will only contain 600 and not 300?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are putting the search value itself as follows:

```
bestPrices.put(entry.getKey(), value);
```

Instead, you have to put the entry's value as follows:

```
bestPrices.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
```